# Android: ExpandableList View crashed on scrolling more then 30 records in Android OS 4.0

Tags: android

The ExpandableList View crashed on scrolling more then 30 records only in Nexus running "ice cream sandwich Android OS 4.0). This problem only occurred in my Nexus phone. It works fine in my emulator even run it on Andriod 4.0 with more then 30 records.

I have used the android inflate feature (to render the layout from XML file) in `getGroupView` and `getChildView()` method of the `BaseExpandableListAdapter` class. If 
If I render the `getChildView()` and `getGroupView()` function using the dynamic `TextView` then it works fine.

The problem only generated during the scroll and also in Android OS 4.0 (nexus) phone otherwise it works fine.

I got following error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:483)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:549)
at com.android.myexample.Custom$MyExpandableListAdapter.getChildView(Custom.java:681)
at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:450)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2012)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:705)
at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:645)
at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4546)
at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:3813)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**the error occured on following code...**

```
childImg.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open((childListDataBean.get(groups.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition).imageId))));
```

Comment: i have updated the description with error message. Thanks for your look up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed this bug by disabling the scrolling catch of the expandablelistview using following...........................................................

```
<ExpandableListView 
android:id="@+id/android:EL1"    
propertiesandroid:overScrollMode="never"
android:scrollingCache="false"
android:transcriptMode="disabled"
android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
android:smoothScrollbar="true"
android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="false"
android:animationCache="false"
android:persistentDrawingCache="none"
android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="false"
android:drawingCacheQuality="low"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look up approaches to manage your memory. You're consuming too much memory than the VM is going to give you. This is your problem, look up talks by Romain Guy he does specific talks about Graphics and Bitmaps.

Comment: Will you give me any idea how can i manage the memory. Can we increase the VM memory from the phone? I ask you because it occures only for Nexus phone.

Comment: Google romain guy and graphics. Specfically I dont think there is an API to increase your VM.. but i'll check.

Comment: Finally I fixed this bug by disabling the scrolling catch of the expandablelistview using following...........................................................propertiesandroid:overScrollMode="never"
android:scrollingCache="false"
android:transcriptMode="disabled"
android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
android:smoothScrollbar="true"
android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="false"
android:animationCache="false"
android:persistentDrawingCache="none"
android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="false"
android:drawingCacheQuality="low"